# Can't seem to find whats with Type Error $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, function, loading, typeerror

I Can't seem to find whats with Type Error $ is not a function. Any one there please help me. The javascript seems to load in a https site, but not on http. So i dont know how to troubleshoot.

[IMG][http://i59.tinypic.com/14smm4l.jpg[/IMG]](http://i59.tinypic.com/14smm4l.jpg%5b/IMG%5d)

UPDATED JQUERY CODE

```
(function($){
    $.timeliner=function(options){
        if($.timeliners==null){
            $.timeliners={options:[]};
            $.timeliners.options.push(options)
        }else{
            $.timeliners.options.push(options)
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
            for(var i=0;i<$.timeliners.options.length;i++){
                startTimeliner($.timeliners.options[i])
            }
        })
    };
    function startTimeliner(options){
        var settings={
            timelineContainer:options["timelineContainer"]||"#timelineContainer",
            startState:options["startState"]||"closed",
            startOpen:options["startOpen"]||[],
            baseSpeed:options["baseSpeed"]||200,
            speed:options["speed"]||4,
            fontOpen:options["fontOpen"]||"1.2em",
            fontClosed:options["fontClosed"]||"1em",
            expandAllText:options["expandAllText"]||"+ expand all",
            collapseAllText:options["collapseAllText"]||"- collapse all"
        };

        function openEvent(eventHeading,eventBody){
            $(eventHeading)
                .removeClass("closed")
                .addClass("open")
                .animate({fontSize:settings.fontOpen}, settings.baseSpeed);
            $(eventBody).show(settings.speed*settings.baseSpeed)
        }

        function closeEvent(eventHeading,eventBody){
            $(eventHeading)
                .animate({fontSize:settings.fontClosed},0)
                .removeClass("open")
                .addClass("closed");
            $(eventBody).hide(settings.speed*settings.baseSpeed)
        }

        if($(settings.timelineContainer).data("started")){
            return
        }else{
            $(settings.timelineContainer).data("started",true);
            $(settings.timelineContainer+" "+".expandAll").html(settings.expandAllText);
            $(settings.timelineContainer+" "+".collapseAll").html(settings.collapseAllText);
            if(settings.startState==="closed"){
                $(settings.timelineContainer+" "+".timelineEvent").hide();
                $.each($(settings.startOpen),function(index,value){
                    openEvent($(value).parent(settings.timelineContainer+" "+".timelineMinor").find("dt a"),$(value))
                })
            }else{
                openEvent($(settings.timelineContainer+" "+".timelineMinor dt a"),$(settings.timelineContainer+" "+".timelineEvent"))
            }
            $(settings.timelineContainer).on("click",".timelineMinor dt",function(){
                var currentId=$(this).attr("id");
                if($(this).find("a").is(".open")){
                    closeEvent($("a",this),$("#"+currentId+"EX"))
                }else{
                    openEvent($("a",this),$("#"+currentId+"EX"))
                }
            });
            $(settings.timelineContainer).on("click","#holdsigns",function(){
                var numEvents=$(this).parents(".timelineMajor").find(".timelineMinor").length;
                var numOpen=$(this).parents(".timelineMajor").find(".open").length;
                if(numEvents>numOpen){
                    openEvent($(this).parents(".timelineMajor").find("dt a","dl.timelineMinor"),$(this).parents(".timelineMajor").find(".timelineEvent"))
                }else{
                    closeEvent($(this).parents(".timelineMajor").find("dl.timelineMinor a"),$(this).parents(".timelineMajor").find(".timelineEvent"))
                }
            });
            $(settings.timelineContainer+" "+".expandAll").click(function(){
                if($(this).hasClass("expanded")){
                    closeEvent($(this).parents(settings.timelineContainer).find("dt a","dl.timelineMinor"),$(this).parents(settings.timelineContainer).find(".timelineEvent"));
                    $(this).removeClass("expanded").html(settings.expandAllText)
                }else{
                    openEvent($(this).parents(settings.timelineContainer).find("dt a","dl.timelineMinor"),$(this).parents(settings.timelineContainer).find(".timelineEvent"));
                    $(this).addClass("expanded").html(settings.collapseAllText)
                }
            })
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You need to format your code properly. Also, did you make sure to include the script link to jQuery in your file?

Comment: post the entire code of the js-file (timeliner-min.js) . The posted fragment does contain syntax-errors, unable to find the real error without seeing the complete code.

Comment: Apparently I'm a loser with nothing better to do than to format other people's code for them, but once you've formatted it properly, it's very obvious that you haven't given us the entire code sample necessary to diagnose your problem. What you've pasted just cuts off at a seemingly random spot in your code dump. Here's a hint: all we really need to see is the first couple lines and the last couple lines of your code.

Comment: @ Travesty3 @ Dr.Molle I'm sorry. Ive updated with the completed code.   First line  (function($){                  last lines: (jQuery);

Comment: Yeah i included the script link @adrichman , i don't know why it doesn't work but it works on local

Comment: I'm betting it's a problem with jQuery not getting included properly. Can you show the code where you include it?

Comment: @travesty3 here's a screenshot http://tinypic.com/r/eafgjl/8

Comment: I see where two other libraries are included, but not jQuery. I think that's your problem. Download jQuery from http://jquery.com/download/ and include the jquery JS file in your page, or [link to their CDN](http://jquery.com/download/#using-jquery-with-a-cdn).

Comment: @Travesty3 When i use cdn it doesnt load the jquery, only works when i use <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>    however, the problem $.timeliner is not a function still appears :(

Comment: I don't know anything about this timeliner library you're using. I see where you are declaring `$.timeliner = function() ...`, but I don't see where you're using it, which is where this error would be generated. Given that you've included a `timeliner` library, I would think that `$.timeliner` was already a function and it appears as though you would be overwriting it by doing `$.timelier = function() ...`, so perhaps that's part of your problem. You should also ensure that your timeliner library is getting included properly. Using Chrome, check the Network tab and make sure it is found.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrapping the code in anonymous function. At the end of your code, do you provide jQuery to the scope?

```
(function($) {
  // Your code in here
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: yes i did. The starting and ending is exactly like what u said